# Lebesgue Integration and Riemann integration of a function

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f= \frac{\sin x }{\sqrt{x}}$ on $[\pi, \infty)$.

Is $f$ Lebesgue integrable?

Is $f$ (improper) Riemann integrable?

I think that $f$ is improper Riemann integrable since, $\int_0 ^\infty f(x) dx = \sqrt{\pi/2} $.

But not sure about the Lebesgue integration.

Also, I know that $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ is neither Riemann or Lebesgue integrable...

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Tip: use `\sin`.

Comment: You are correct; $\int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx=\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2}$ as an improper Riemann Integral. And inasmuch as $\int_0^\pi \frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt{x}}\,dx<\infty$, $f$ is RI on $[\pi,\infty]$.  However, $f$ is not LI on $[\pi,\infty]$since $\int_\pi^\infty \left|\frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt{x}}\right|\,dx=\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ and $\frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{x}}$ are Riemann integrable, that follows from the Dirichlet criterion. On the other hand, none of them is Lebesgue integrable. To see that consider part of the domain $[\pi, \infty]$ on which $|\sin x|>1/2$, call it $\mathcal{A}$. It is easy to see that
$$
\int_{\mathcal{A}}\Big|\frac{\sin x}{x}\Big|\,dx=\infty
$$
(write $\mathcal{A}$ explicitly and then estimate from below the integral by a suitable diverging series). It also shows that $\frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{x}}$ is not Lebesgue integrable on $[\pi, \infty]$, since
$$
\frac{|\sin x|}{\sqrt{x}}>\frac{|\sin x|}{x},\quad x\in[\pi,\infty).
$$